# where do timers get persisted ejb

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a quick question
now I am working with timers in EJB
and I create a timer like this:

```
timerService.createCalendarTimer(
new ScheduleExpression().second("*/60").minute("*").hour("*"), new TimerConfig(
"mainTimer", true));
```

now when I shutdown the server and restart, this timer is active
I understand I have perstiance = true
but I am not specefying the datasource
where are these being persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard place where the persistent timers are saved between server restarts. They might be saved on a database or on the file system as Jboss 7 does by default. This should be configurable, but most of the time you don't need to change the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what application server you're using, but for example in GlassFish the timer service is preconfigured to use an embedded Java DB database.

Answer (score 1):

As for WebSphere 6.1 default EJB Timer database is Derby.